# How do I delete joomla template?

Tags: joomla

I installed a new template for my joomla site but after that I have no access template manager. It only becomes a completely white page in Firefox and Opera says that "currently unable to handle the request." Is there any way to delete a template outside of the webadmin interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete through your ftp client like filezilla. Open filezilla, login to your server and the delete the template. May be the template comes with some plugins or else how can just by installing it started showing error unless you use that template. Possibility is: i) You might have installed a template for older version. ii) You might have installed a plugin with the template that was autopublished. iii) You messed up some setting files.

I suggest you to open file manager, go to templates and then delete that particular template. Also when asking please ask providing all details like name of template, link of template etc.